# Cascading two CSS codes with css-sprite

Tags: html, css, class, sprite, cascade

I have an HTML code :

```html
<li class="bath-icon"><a href="bath.php">bath</a></li>
```

Where `class="bath-icon"` is defined in CSS as :

```css
.bath-icon a {
    background: url('images/room_bath.png');
    background-size: auto 40%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 20px;
    background-color: #7E7C14;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Now I want to replace background image `room_bath.png` with an image from a sprite image with values as:

```css
.room_bath {
     width: 107px; 
     height: 64px;
     background: url('images/sprite.png') -0 -952px;
}
```

Can anyone help me how both CSS can be cascaded and background image from sprite is inserted in `.bath-icon` class?

Answer (score 0):

You can create variable in css and refer the variable in your css declaration.

```
:root {
  --room-bath-bg: url('images/sprite.png') -0 -952px;
}


.bath-icon a {
   background: var(--room-bath-bg);
   background-size: auto 40%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: 50% 20px;
   background-color: #7E7C14;
   opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Like above you can create your variable and refer in any places. The variable declaration should start with `--` to identify the system.

***NOTE:*** This mehtod is supported by only modern browsers.

Refer this [W3 Schools CSS3 Variables](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp) to learn more details about this.

Comment: thanks Suresh. But sprite image of '''.room_bath {
     width: 107px; 
     height: 64px;
     background: url('images/sprite.png') -0 -952px;
}''' has width and height parameters as well. Without it, specific sprite  image does not load, rather whole sprite is visible in the main class of .bath-icon. The class .bath-icon also has background-size property which is clashing with sprite image size.

Comment: for that you have to create sepearate variable and apply

Comment: I can create another variable for background size, but that clashes with background-size of bath-icon class.

Comment: If that is the case then apply both the classes for anchor. But write the css declaration `room-bath` for last. So that it will overwrite the same property of `bath-icon`. If still not overwrite then use `important` in `room-bath`. If this approach works then no need any css variables.

Comment: important property when added to size, only changes the shape of bath_icon rather than selecting image from sprite. Resultant, the whole sprite is displayed within the icon rather than specific image.